# Get specific href from current page

Tags: php, dom

Trying to extract an href path (#navbar a href that ends in $pg) from the current page.

Getting a warning on the first foreach:

```
file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty.
```

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
include_once 'path/to/simple_html_dom.php';

$pg = 'c.html';
echo 'Page: ' . $pg . "<br />"; // Correct: c.html
$cpath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo var_dump($cpath).": Current Path"."<br />";  // Correct: /copyr/index.php
$cfile = basename($cpath);
echo 'Current File: ' . $cfile . "<br />";  // Correct: index.php
$html = file_get_html($cfile);

foreach($html->find(sprintf('#navbar a[href=%s]', $pg)) as $path) {  // BROKEN
    echo 'Path: ' . $path."<br />";
    $tpath = $path."/".$pg;
    echo 'Total Path: ' . $tpath;
    $html->clear();
}

$html = file_get_html($tpath);

foreach($html->find('#testdiv2') as $ret) {
  echo $ret;
  $html->clear();
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `file_get_contents` in your code

Comment: I guess that would be the `file_get_html()` wrapper, are you sure that  `$cfile`is not empty?

Comment: `file_get_html` is indeed part of a library that uses file_get_contents. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes, I'm using simplehtmldom What's wrong w/ the foreach loop? - Parti

Comment: @MathieuImbert Can you help me with actual code. Golez's generalizations aren't helping me - I'm a newbie & I need some help - please

Answer (score 2):

`basename` returns the last part of a path. If `REQUEST_URI` ends in a `/` (as in `http://yourdomain.arg/`, basename returns an empty string, while `file_get_html` expects an uri or file name.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure it's the answer, but it's a good guess, and it's good to fix anyway.

Comment: Hmmmm..  Since that is auto-generated, I expect index.php or index.html for example, but I guess someone could set up a page ending in hashtags, etc.  How would I ensure that Request_URI will always look at the current page? Also, I still need help fixing the first foreach loop ;) See above code for example output - Parti

Comment: REQUEST_URI does point to the current page, but it is the `URI` of the page, which doesn't necessarily match the file name. Often, index.php will be the default file, in which case it doesn't need to be in the URL. The warning you get is not on the `foreach`, but on the line above, it's because `$cFile` is empty.

Comment: @GolezTrol - OK, I guess that's starting to generally make sense on the why, but I'm a total newbie at PHP, so could you show me what code to use to make sure $cfile has the file name in it - Thanks

Comment: The filename of what? Not sure which file name you want to have. You can get the file name of the current script, but that doesn't contain html. You got a variable `$pg` which contains `c.html`, but you don't use that at all. Isn't that where you went wrong?

Comment: @GolezTrol - The filename of the current page.

Comment: @GolezTrol - $pg will be used later - ignore that - It's not what I need right now.  I need to assign $cfile to the current page name.

Comment: There is no 'current page file name'. You got the url, which is *not* a file path per se, and doesn't even always have a path in it, like I showed in my answer. And you got your script, which is a php script file, which has a name which isn't necessarily in the url. A whole site (with all different urls, including images and all) could be handled by a single php script. So what you need to figure out, is which exact file you want to read, and where you want that filename to come from. How is your script supposed to know which file it should read?

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as adding a line like: 'if ($cFile == '') $cFile = 'index.html'`. That way, you can read the file name from the url (like you do now) and fall back to reading index.html when you got an url without path information.

Comment: @GolezTrol I think you're on to something w/ the if statement. I forget to mention (sorry) the script needs to reference the current page automatically - Ie, won't be able to manually type in a hardset fallback value like 'index.php'